# Android Studio Google Glass: How to take a picture with voice command

Tags: java, controls, google-glass, google-gdk, voice

Ideally I'm trying to use a voice input from the user in voice_trigger.xml and store it in strings.xml so that I can compare the string variable in Camera activity, such that if it matches, take a picture and save it.

I'm not quite sure how to implement this. Does it sound like I have the right idea for solving this?

Below: **voice_trigger.xml, strings.xml, CameraActivity.java**

voice_trigger.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- For more information about voice trigger, check out: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/starting-glassware -->
<trigger keyword="Visual tracker">
<!--    <input prompt="@string/glass_tracking_prompt" /> -->
        <input interaction ="@string/take_picture"/>
    <constraints network="true"
        camera="true" />
    </trigger>
```

strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">GlassTracker</string>
    <string name="title_activity_live_card_service">Tracking Prime LiveCard</string>
    <string name="title_activity_live_card_renderer">Tracking Prime Activity</string>
    <string name="action_stop">Close App</string>
    <string name="action_tune_track">Tune Tracker</string>
    <string name="action_start_track">Start Tracking</string>
    <string name="action_stop_track">Stop Tracking</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello visual tracker!</string>
    <string name="glass_tracking_trigger">Visual tracker</string>
    <string name="glass_tracking_prompt">Tap to tune</string>
    <string name="take_picture">Take a picture</string>
</resources>
```

CameraActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.FileObserver;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;

import com.google.android.glass.content.Intents;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by
 */
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

    private CameraSurfaceView cameraView;


    private static final int TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST = 1;

    //Take the picture only if the string take_picture from voice control allows for it.
    private void takePicture() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST);
    }




    @Override
    /*Take out ints */
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String thumbnailPath = data.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_THUMBNAIL_FILE_PATH);
            String picturePath = data.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_PICTURE_FILE_PATH);

            processPictureWhenReady(picturePath);
            // TODO: Show the thumbnail to the user while the full picture is being
            // processed.
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    private void processPictureWhenReady(final String picturePath) {
        final File pictureFile = new File(picturePath);

        if (pictureFile.exists()) {
            // The picture is ready; process it.
        } else {
            // The file does not exist yet. Before starting the file observer, you
            // can update your UI to let the user know that the application is
            // waiting for the picture (for example, by displaying the thumbnail
            // image and a progress indicator).

            final File parentDirectory = pictureFile.getParentFile();
            FileObserver observer = new FileObserver(parentDirectory.getPath(),
                    FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE | FileObserver.MOVED_TO) {
                // Protect against additional pending events after CLOSE_WRITE
                // or MOVED_TO is handled.
                private boolean isFileWritten;

                @Override
                public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
                    if (!isFileWritten) {
                        // For safety, make sure that the file that was created in
                        // the directory is actually the one that we're expecting.
                        File affectedFile = new File(parentDirectory, path);
                        isFileWritten = affectedFile.equals(pictureFile);

                        if (isFileWritten) {
                            stopWatching();

                            // Now that the file is ready, recursively call
                            // processPictureWhenReady again (on the UI thread).
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    processPictureWhenReady(picturePath);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            observer.startWatching();
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initiate CameraView
        cameraView = new CameraSurfaceView(this); //Calls CameraSurfaceView

        // Set the view
        this.setContentView(cameraView);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Do not hold the camera during onResume
        if (cameraView != null) {
            cameraView.releaseCamera();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Do not hold the camera during onPause
        if (cameraView != null) {
            cameraView.releaseCamera();
        }
    }






}
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the voice_triggers.xml file,  will listen for a voice command. As you speak your command to the device, voiceRes will populate with what you say, since that is an array of type string, it ideally needs to be converted to a string. Then it is simple to do comparisons based on what the user said. Also, make sure to include brackets around the comparison, or the if statement won't work. This was a solution that I quickly discovered, I'm sure there are many ways to do it.

In the `onCreate()` method, right after `this.setContentView(cameraView);`

```
ArrayList<String> voiceRes =getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
String Voicedata = voiceRes.toString();


 if(Voicedata.equals("[take a picture]")
   {
        takepicture();

   }
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?

Comment: You should add the explanation to your answer using the edit button. ;)